# jQuery Word Counter, exclude default text

Tags: jquery

My code:

```
 function wordCount()
    {   
        if ($("#id_COMMENT_PRO).val() == "What did you like about the product?") {
            // do not subtract from count
        }

        if ($("#id_COMMENT_NEG).val() == "What didn't you like about the product?) {
            // do not subtract from count
        }

        var num = 100 - $("#id_COMMENT_PRO").val().length - $("#id_COMMENT_NEG").val().length;
        if (num < 0) {
            num = 0;
            }

        $('#count').text('Words left: ' + num);


    }
```

The function counts from both text areas but I need it to exclude the default text, I started to write the IF statements but I cannot think of a way to prevent it from counting.

Comment: Could you display the default text in a location other than in the input, such as in a span that sits behind the input? That way your word counter doesn't have to know about the default text handling.

Comment: Can't you just use the `placeholder` attribute on the textareas? That way you don't have to mess around with anything

Comment: No, unfortunately I inherited this code, the textareas are populated through a switch statement based on their id_

Comment: Please show the entirety of the code (HTML and JS) so someone can help you debug.

Comment: You're missing doublequotes in several places, the syntax highlighting shows that pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the logic slightly (this is assuming the default text is removed once the user types something):

```
function wordCount() {
    var num = 100;

    if ($("#id_COMMENT_PRO").val() !== "What did you like about the product?") {
        num -= $("#id_COMMENT_PRO").val().length;
    }

    if ($("#id_COMMENT_NEG").val() !== "What didn't you like about the product?") {
        num -= $("#id_COMMENT_NEG").val().length;
    }

    num = num > 0 ? num : 0;

    $('#count').text('Words left: ' + num);
}
```